# sas/sql logic needed

Tags: sql, sas

I have a data with SSN and Open date and have to calculate if a customer has opened 2 or more accounts within 120 days based on the open_date field. I know to use INTCK/INTNX functions but it requires 2 date fields, not sure how to apply the same logic on a single field for same customer.Please suggest.

```
SSN  account         Open_date
xyz  000123          12/01/2015
xyz  112344          11/22/2015
xyz  893944          04/05/2016
abc  992343          01/10/2016
abc  999999          03/05/2016
123  111123          07/16/2015
123  445324          10/12/2015
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists` or `join`:

```
proc sql;
     select distinct SSN
     from t
     where exists (select 1
                   from t t2
                   where t2.SSN = t.SSN and
                         t2.open_date between t.open_date and t.open_date + 120
                  );
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, but i only have one table. To use the logic you shared it must have 2 tables right ?

Comment: @BharatGuda No, it's called a self-join - join the table to itself.

Comment: @BharatGuda . . . That is what the table aliases are for.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it using `JOIN` :

```
proc sql;
  create table want as
  select *
  from have
  where SSN in
    (select a.SSN
    from have a
    inner join have b
    on a.SSN=b.SSN
    where intck('day', a.Open_date, b.Open_Date)+1 < 120)
  ;
quit;
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitry, but i have the data only in 1 table, there is no 2nd table to join.

Comment: It's the same table `have` joined to itself

Answer (score 0):

Just a slightly different solution here - use the dif function which calculates the number of days between accounts being open.

```
proc sort data=have;
by ssn open_date;
run;

data want;
set have;
by ssn;

days_between_open = dif(open_date);

if first.ssn then days_between_open = .;

*if 0 < days_between_open < 120 then output;
run;
```

Then you can filter the table above as required. I've left it commented out at this point because you haven't specified how you want your output table.